# The polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_nx^n$ has a zero in $[0,1]$ under a given condition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Show that the polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_nx^n$ has a zero in $[0,1]$ when it is given that, $$ \frac{a_0}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{a_1}{2\cdot 3}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=0.$$

First we consider the function, $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{a_0}{1\cdot 2}x^2+\frac{a_1}{2\cdot 3}x^3+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)}x^{n+2}$. Then, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$. Then by Rolle's theorem,  $\exists$ $y\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(y)=0$ which gives, $\displaystyle a_0y+\frac{a_1}{2}y^2+\cdots +\frac{a_n}{n+1}y^{n+1}=0$.

Next consider, $\displaystyle g(z)=a_0z+\frac{a_1}{2}z^2+\cdots +\frac{a_n}{n+1}z^{n+1}$. Then, $g(0)=0$ and $g(y)=0$. So by Rolle's theorem, $\exists$ $w\in (0,y)\subset (0,1)$ such that $g'(w)=p(w)=0.$ Hence the proof is complete.

Is this proof is correct? I think it is correct. But I am looking for an another proof so that I can avoid two times consideration of functions such as $f$ and $g$.

Comment: The proof is correct, well described.

Comment: @ André Nicolas) Please see the next question.

Comment: I can't think of a way to avoid differentiating twice, or integrating twice.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554262/sufficient-condition-for-a-polynomial-to-have-roots-in-0-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is correct (but note it is Rolle, not Roll). You can also use the fact that
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x p(t)dt=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{(k+1)(k+2)}=0$$

Now if you suppose that $p(t)\not =  0$ on $[0,1]$, then  (as $p$ is continuous)there exists $m$ such that $p(t)\geq m>0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ (or $p(t)\leq -m<0$), and this show that the multiple integral is $\geq m/2$, a contradiction.

EDIT: With only one integration:

As $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}$, we get
$$\int_0^1(1-t)p(t)dt=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_k}{k+2} =0$$
and we finish easily.