# Prove that polynomial has a root between $(0;1)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Prove that if for some natural $p>0$,
> $$
> \frac{a_1}{(p+1)} + \frac{a_2}{(p+2)} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{(p+n)} = 0,
> $$
> then the polynomial $a_nx^{n-1} + a_{n-1}x^{n-2} + \cdots + a_1$ has root in $(0, 1)$.

That polynomial looks like it might be a derivative of some other polynomial, and I know that:
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x - \alpha_i}
$$
where $\alpha_i$ is a root of $f(x)$.

However I can't figure out if it is of any help here.

Could somebody please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me it looks as if the expression that is set equal to 0 might be the *integral* of some polynomial.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497775/prove-that-sum-k-0n-a-k-xk-0-has-at-least-1-real-root-if-sum-k-0?rq=1

Comment: are you fimiliar with Rolle's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should precise that the coefficients are real numbers, otherwise the conclusion may be false.

The assumption yields $\int_0^1 x^pf(x) dx = 0$, where $f$ is the polynomial considered. If $f$ had no zero on $]0,1[$, it would be positive everywhere positive everywhere or negative everywhere on $]0,1[$, which would give a contradiction.